# Visual Studio 2017 C++ solution not building after upgrade to 15.9.3

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've just upgraded Visual Studio 2017 to 15.9.13. After doing so, 2 of the 3 C++ solutions I am currently working on no longer build. The following errors are shown:

```
1>The value "Value is not created." is not of type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.IVsLoggerEventProcessor2" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
1>Parameter name: value
1>Error: The value "Value is not created." is not of type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.IVsLoggerEventProcessor2" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
1>Parameter name: value
```

The other one builds ok. This happens when trying to build/compile/clean anything in the solution. The two non-building solutions are creating exes. The building solution is creating a DLL. I've inspected the vcxproj files to see what the differences are and tried copying various bits between them but that makes no difference. Googling doesn't give any answers either.
the only reference I can even find to IVsLoggerEventProcessor2 is on 
[this page](https://github.com/microsoft/VSProjectSystem/blob/master/doc/overview/breaking_changes_visual_studio_2019.md).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the .vs directory in the project folder seems to have done the trick.